# Native Library already loaded in another Maven plugin's classloader

Tags: java, sqlite, jvm, classloader, native

I would like to run two third-party Maven plugins using the [Xerial JDBC driver](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) for SQLite. The plugin configuration roughly looks like this:

```xml
<plugins>
    <!-- reset database with the SQL Maven plugin -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>...</executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
                <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>

    [...]

    <!-- generate source code with the jOOQ Maven plugin -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
        <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
        <executions>...</executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
                <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>

    [...]
```

Now this SQLite JDBC driver loads a native library, internally, which causes the following error to appear in the second plugin's execution:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library 
C:\Users\Lukas\AppData\Local\Temp\sqlite-3.7.151-amd64-sqlitejdbc.dll
already loaded in another classloader
```

The workaround is to comment out one of the plugins.

Is there a proper way to circumvent this problem without making any assumptions about the system on which this runs? I'd like to create self-contained tests with the above, which should run on any system, i.e. putting stuff into system library paths is not a solution here. Can this be solved with Maven? Or do any of the above plugins or (more likely) the JDBC driver need to be fixed?

Comment: We have the same problem. We are using maven-com4j-plugin to generate a dll wrapper class which is used later on in the build process within a Java programm that is started by exec-maven-plugin. Different ClassLoaders but same com4j dll. Our workaround was to put the com4j dll in Maven's bin folder. So we have _different_ dlls which can be loaded from the different ClassLoaders